# Trying to get Juypter Notebook to work on my chrome book through the Linux beta

Tags: linux, python, chrome-book

So I am trying to get Jupyter Notebook to get to work on my Chromebook. I am using this guide
https://www.codecademy.com/articles/jupyter-notebook-chromebook
and every time I input this code

```
sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev libhdf5-dev
```

I get this

```
Err:1 https://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.19.181-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:1::644 443]
Err:2 https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 libssl-dev amd64 1.1.1d-0+deb10u6
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:1::644 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.19.181-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:1::644 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.1.1d-0+deb10u6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:1::644 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I did download libffi_3.4.2-1ubuntu5.debian.tar.xz to hopefully fix it and I put it into my Linux files but it only helped a little.

Ok I try to an `sudo apt-get update` but it returns

```
N: Repository 'https://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' changed its 'Version' value from '10.9' to '10.11'
E: Repository 'https://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable' to 'oldstable'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
E: Repository 'https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable' to 'oldstable'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details
```

so I am trying to figure out to get around it but all the stuff I researched makes no sense.

Comment: The errors say they are having difficulty finding packages in the repository, at the end it says to attempt to remedy by running `apt-get update`.  What is the output when you run that command?  Does it fix the issue if you run `apt install` again afterward?

Comment: [E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)] this was when I ran apt-get update and I tried to find a way to fix this so I did download libffi_3.4.2-1ubuntu5.debian.tar.xz and put it into my linux files but it only helped alittle.

Comment: this is from apt install [Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?]

Comment: Thanks for adding more information on the steps; it is best to [edit] your original post, and include the various log output blocks in code blocks as shown in https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code -- that will help us to be able to get all the info we need w/o having to read through the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like apt is refusing to update.  You are getting the 404 error because the specific package versions you are trying to install are no-longer hosted.

This would normally be fixed by simply typing `apt-get update` but in your case apt is refusing to do this because the repository has changed it's name.

You should be able to fix this with:

```
apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update
```